# How to hash JAAS j_password on client?

Tags: java, tomcat, jaas

I was just running through a few basic tutorials on using JAAS in web applications.

I got everything setup fine but noticed that the j_password parameter is sent from the client browser in clear text.

Is there a way to make JAAS hash this value before sending it?

My application is running on Tomcat 7, so I don't know if this could achieved through some server specific setting or via some web app setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [The definitive guide to form-based website authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549/the-definitive-guide-to-form-based-website-authentication)

In short: Client side password hashing requires **javascript on the client**; there is no such standard if you use form based authentication that you can simply enable on the server. In any case, **make sure your connection is encrypted (HTTP over SSL)**. Then it is less/not important to hash passwords on client side.